# VBA for Excel 2007 and above

Tags: vba, select, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have written some VBA code that looks at a column, finds the next cell in that column which contains data, and sets the cells in between the two as a range.  This was originally written for an Excel 2003 Workbook. And of course the same command does not work for a 2007 and above workbook.  Can anyone help translate this for 2010 Excel VBA.

Here is the original Code:

```
Dim first As Integer
Dim Last As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

n = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count - 2
Range("A3").Select

For i = 1 To n
    first = (ActiveCell.Row + 1)
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Last = (ActiveCell.Row - 1)
    Range("J" & first & ":J" & Last).Select
    Selection.Value = "=J$" & (first - 1)
    Range("A" & Last + 1).Select
Next i
```

When I run it in Excel 2010.  Instead of finding the next cell in Column A that contains data it just select the entire column.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That code doesn't do what you think it does. Can you show some sample data and sample output?

Comment: I will try to weed it down.  It is part of a much larger Macro.  As I do that let me explain a little better what it is doing:

Comment: Let me explain a little better what it is doing:  Start on cell A3.  Assign Cell below A3 (A4) to the variable First.  Move down to next cell in column A that contains information, then back up 1 row.  Assign that row number to variable First.  In Column J- select- J(First) : J(Last).  In each of those cells make cell value equal to J(First).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GoDownList()
Dim first As Integer
Dim Last As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer

first = Range("A3").Row
Last = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
Range("J" & first & ":J" & Last).Value = "=J$" & (first - 1)

Do
    first = Range("A" & Last).End(xlDown).Row
    Last = Range("A" & first).End(xlDown).Row
    Range("J" & first & ":J" & Last).Value = "=J$" & (first - 1)
    If Range("A" & Last).End(xlDown).Row > 1000000 Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

I think your code doesnt work because you used `Selection.Value` instead of `Selection.Formula`.

Comment: Thanks,  I found the issue- it is not in the code it is in the download of the report.  When we download the report in .XLSX format-(it is an SSRS Report) for some reason empty cells are not showing as empty cells.  Just for a test I ran a Goto Special- Blanks and nothing was highlighted.  I had to trick it to see that there are blanks in the column.  Other than that, the code works perfectly. It also works perfectly in 2003 formats. Thank you all for your help.